# Show scroll-y after certain height but height is dynamic

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a div with following style: height:300px;overflow-y:scroll;. I want it to scroll after 400px but should have height according to the content in it.

For example, if the content in it is 100px, then, the height of div should be 100 without scroll. But, if the height exceeds 400px, it should show scroll.

How can do it?

Answer (score 1):

you need to set `max-height: 400px` to your parent `div` along with `overflow`

```css
div{
  max-height: 400px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons ectetur elit. Vestibulum nec odios Suspe ndisse cursus mal suada faci lisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametion consectetur elit. Vesti bulum nec.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons ectetur elit. Vestibulum nec odios Suspe ndisse cursus mal suada faci lisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametion consectetur elit. Vesti bulum nec.
  </p>
</div>
```